# How do I use yarn to manage client dependencies?

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

I am moving towards managing client side dependencies using yarn and npm and I can't wrap my head around how to use these dependencies in my web site.

So far I have installed the necessary dependencies (i.e. ngeohash) using `yarn add`. I can see the dependency the node-modules directory.

My problem is that I have a web page (index.html) where I am going to display a map from a geohashes returned from an ajax request. However, the entry point for the application is index.js. I don't understand why that is. I see examples using require but when I add the following to my `<script>` element in index.html:

```
var geohash = require('ngeohash');
```

I get this error:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require
```

I've looked at the getting started tutorial but nowhere does it show one how to use the dependencies once they are installed! What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Usually npm/yarn packages are used when use some webpack or another javascript module bundler. I never use yarn for pure HTML/JS/CSS application, so I can be wrong, but you can read about [ecmascript modules on MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) and get some ideas. You can too read about [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) and if you can use it on your app, you will run yarn/npm without troubles.